# How to layout/model data between View Controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model

I am trying to recreate the Notes App with CloudKit functionality (I currently am just saving data in arrays). I’m trying to work out how to lay it out locally before I add on CloudKit. I am having a bit of trouble understanding how my project should be laid out. I have 3 View/View Controller documents which segue to each other and 2 Model Documents witch are for the Folder and Note structs:

```
struct Folder {
    var name: String
    var icon: UIImage?
    var contents: [Note]
    }

struct Note {
    var name: String
    var text: String
}
```

The order of the app would go - FolderTableVC -> NotesTableVC -> Note.

Where should my actual arrays of data be kept so I can access and change them on all screens? Should the Folder array be kept on the FolderTableVC then sent to the NotesTableVC  (this is what I am doing know but it seems inefficient) and so on or should I have an overarching array/document that I can access and change data from any VC?

If someone could give me some advice in regards to what this structure should be, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use coredata.. Now your every controller connected to the DB.. and fetch data directly from there and its persistence store too, so dont need to worry abt.

Comment: @dahiya_boy With Core Data where would I put the actual Core Data Code? In every View Controller? Does that mean I wouldn't need the Model Files?

Comment: Create `CoreData` and make **DBManager** class. In **DBManager** , write func for fetch, update, delete, insert code and now from VC just call them with required params. This is MVC that manage your hectic. Everyone have their own style so you can do things in your style. I got link that could help you out, check -> https://medium.com/@maddy.lucky4u/swift-4-core-data-part-3-creating-a-singleton-core-data-refactoring-insert-update-delete-9811af2fcf75